# Regex: Find/Replace All Substrings Without a Given String Before?

Tags: visual-studio, regex, replace

I need to find all strings without a given string before it.

For Instance:

```
Find: "someValue"
```

**All results with "function(" before them should be ignored

The Visual Studio regular expression **would find this**:

```
value = someValue
```

And **Ignore something looking like this**:

```
function(someValue)
```

What is the best way to go about this?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

You could use negative look-behind:

```
(?<!function\()someValue
```

Answer (score 2):

You said

> The Visual Studio regular expression would find this:

Combined with the title of your question, that makes me think you're trying to do something in a search and replace dialog in Visual Studio, rather than using a regex in an application.

If that's the case, then I think you might be out of luck; Visual Studio's regular expressions aren't very powerful, and they have a rather odd syntax that doesn't seem to be used anywhere else!

My advice would be to either use a different text editor, or use the regex described by [SilentGhost](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12855/silentghost) in a .NET application (or PowerShell script) to do the replacement for you. When I need to do regex stuff in an editor and Studio doesn't cut it, I tend to use [TextPad](http://www.textpad.com/). It's not very pretty, but it's powerful and has great macro support.

Incidentally, if you want to use PowerShell to do it, this will search `foo.js`, and copy the output to `fooNew.js`:

```
(get-content D:\junk\foo.js) -replace
    '(?<!function\()someValue', 'someOtherValue' > D:\junk\fooNew.js
```